# How to disable share button displayed on android google map

Tags: android, google-maps

I am using GoogleMap Fragment to show map on android. When run the app and map is displayed it shows big round Share button at right bottom corner of the device screen which i don't want. I want to hide it. Is there any setting option for the same.

[image]

I have tried following option through activity in onMapReady but no luck,

```
mMap.getUiSettings().setMapToolbarEnabled(false);
```

Also checked xml attributes but there is no such option

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
  android:id="@+id/map"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  map:cameraBearing="112.5"
  map:cameraTargetLat="-33.796923"
  map:cameraTargetLng="150.922433"
  map:cameraTilt="30"
  map:cameraZoom="13"
  map:mapType="normal"
  map:uiCompass="false"
  map:uiRotateGestures="true"
  map:uiScrollGestures="false"
  map:uiTiltGestures="true"
  map:uiZoomControls="false"
  map:uiZoomGestures="true"/>
```

Any help will be appreciated...Thanks

Comment: Are you sure this is part of Map Fragment and not your Activity? Cause i never seen a Map with `FloatingActionButton`

Comment: I have not added share button like this on the layout anywhere..

Comment: search FloatingActionButton in you XML Layout and remove it from the Layout